# Instantiate array in F#?

Tags: arrays, f#, functional-programming

In C# I'd write something like

```
MyType arr = new MyType[10];
```

to alloc `arr` as array which has 10 items of type `MyType`.

**How to do the same in F# ??**

```
let mutable arr = ?????????????
```

Comment: Do you really need an array?  F# and functional languages tend to like linked lists, with lots of syntax support for them...

Comment: There are still plenty of times when arrays are the right choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To initialise the array to the default (e.g. null or zero), use Array.zeroCreate:

```
let arr : int array = Array.zeroCreate 10
```

To initialise with a value, use Array.init.

Comment: Note also 'Array.create' and 'Array.init', see the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370273(VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could conceivably be interested in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591175/initialize-array-to-blank-custom-type-ocaml) although it is in an OCaml context.